# My LogOut button don't work

Tags: android

I am building an app where I have an option for log in. I make that when token exist then user go directly to Main Activity. And that is okay but when I click on LogOut button it sends me again on that page where is LogOut button instead sending me to the LogIn activity. Why is that?
My MainActivity:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences shf = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);

        if(strPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        viewToken = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tokenView);
        String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("result");


        initializeInjector();
        initialize();
    }
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("OnResume", "Ovo je onResume");


        SharedPreferences shf = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);

        if(strPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();

    }
   buttonOk = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", "value");
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
```

This is my LogIn activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreateLogIn", "Ovo je onCreateLogIna");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    SharedPreferences shf = getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strPref = shf.getString("token", null);

    if(strPref != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

That buttonOk in Main Activity is the logOut button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is view in your main activity?

Comment: That is inflanter which sends me to the WrongUSerFragment

Comment: It's not clear what button is the logout button. You should preferably update your variables so they say logout

Comment: Please also make sure to check if the user is allowed to log in when **entering your `MainActivity`** because (at least rooted) people can open the activity without having to log in.

Comment: where have you defined it ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the below code to oncreate method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

buttonOk = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);

    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().remove("token").commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", "value");
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your `OnClickListener` you are using `"Token Prefs"` preferences:

```
getSharedPreferences("Token Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in Login and Main activities you are using  `Token pref` :

```
getSharedPreferences("Token pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you are not manipulating the same preferences change it to `Token pref` in your `OnClickListener`

**EDIT :**
i didnt noticed that, as @SaravInfern said you have to move your `OnClickListener` code and `buttonOk = (Button)findViewById(....)` to OnCreate method.